Возникла проблема с развертыванием Spring MVC приложения на Tomcat. я получаю ошибку HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено
у меня возникла проблема с развертыванием Spring MVC приложения на Tomcat. Когда я перехожу по URL http://localhost:8080/myApp/admin, я получаю ошибку HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено.
Структура проекта:
├───.idea
├───src
│   └───main
│       ├───java
│       │   └───ru
│       │       └───my
│       │           └───app
│       │               └───HelloController.java
│       ├───resources
│       └───webapp
│           └───WEB-INF
│               └───views
│                   └───admin.html
└───target
    ├───classes
    │   └───ru
    │       └───my
    │           └───app
    └───generated-sources
        └───annotations

Контроллер:
package ru.my.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String adminPanel() {
        return "admin";
    }
}

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.my.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myApp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <spring.version>6.1.11</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring and Thymeleaf dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>myApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="myApp" version="3.1">

  <display-name>myApp</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering/>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>

applicationContextMVC.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.my.app"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*"/>
    </bean>

</beans>

Вопрос:
Что может быть причиной ошибки HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено при переходе по URL http://localhost:8080/myApp/admin? Какие дополнительные шаги я могу предпринять для диагностики и исправления этой проблемы?

Еще можно глянуть логи самого tomcat на наличие ошибок.

По всей видимости, GetMapping('/admin') принимает запросы с http://localhost:8080/admin.
Это должно помочь:
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/myApp/admin")
    public String adminPanel() {
        return "admin";
    }
}

